# How to extract fields for specific line numbers that are passed as parameters to a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have a file named `data.txt` with the following content:

```
 1           aFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 2           bFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 3           cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 4           dFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 5           eFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 6           fFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 7           gFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 8           hFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
 9           iFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
10           jFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
11           kFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf        IT524234
```

Please note that the first field is the line number.

Now I want to construct a shell script such that I could call that script with some line number arguments  and it should print out the 1st and 2nd field of the corresponding line numbers in `data.txt`. For example:
`get.sh 1 3 5` should print:

```
1           aFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
3           cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
5           eFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

I think awk can be used for printing only 1st and 2nd field but I am stuck at filtering only specific lines based on the arguments passed to the shell script. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In awk, you could collect the line numbers to an array and read through the file once, printing the lines that are mentioned in the array:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -v lines="$*" 'BEGIN { split(lines, a, "[, ]"); 
                           for (i in a) b[a[i]] = 1;}
                   NR in b {print $1, $2}' < data.txt
```

The `split()` splits the variable `lines` along spaces and commas to array `a`, and the `for` loop builds the array `b` such that the *keys* of that array contain the lines we're interested in. Then `NR in b` just checks if the key matching the current line number exists.

Note that that will print each line only once, regardless of how many times it exists in the input, and the lines will be printed input numeric order, not the order given by the argument:

```
$ bash get.sh 7 3 3
3 cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
7 gFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

(`get.sh 7,3,3` works too)

Comment: +1. nice enhancement with the space or comma delimiter.  stolen for my perl RE-based version.

Answer (score 1):

Put the below lines in a text file and name it as get.sh. then make it executable .

```
#!/bin/sh
## this is GNU sed
sed -En "
  $(printf '%sbp\n' "$@" "d;")
  :p;s/\S+/&\n/2;P
" data.txt
```

---

Now invoke the script as shown:

```
chmod +x ./get.sh
./get.sh 1 3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `bash` script builds a  `sed` script  that will modify and display the lines by the numbers provided on the command line:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

sed_script=()
for lineno do
        sed_script+=( -e "$lineno ba" )
done

sed "${sed_script[@]}" \
        -e 'd' -e ':a' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$//' <data.txt
```

or, for `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

for lineno do
    set -- "$@" -e "$lineno ba"
    shift
done

sed "$@" -e 'd' -e ':a' -e 's/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$//' <data.txt
```

If executed as `./get.sh 1 3 5`, both of these scripts would end up executing the command

```bsh
sed -e '1 ba' -e '3 ba' -e '5 ba' -e d -e :a -e 's/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$//' <data.txt
```

This corresponds to the `sed` script

```
1 ba
3 ba
5 ba
d
:a
s/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$//
```

The substitution `s/[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]*$//` would delete the last column in the data (the last series of spaces or tabs followed a series of non-spaces and non-tabs at the end of the line).  The rest of the `sed` code makes sure that the execution branches to the `:a` label if we're on one of the lines that we want to output (this is what `ba` does), and that the current line is otherwise removed with `d`.

You could modify this and delete the hard-coded redirection in from `data.txt` in the script.  Instead, you could redirect any data stream you wished to process:

```
$ ./get.sh 1 2 9 <data.txt
 1           aFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
 2           bFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
 9           iFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

---

A similar approach in `awk`:  Give the `awk` code a bunch of space-delimited line numbers from the script's command line (the code below gets these from the `lineno` environment variable set up by the calling shell). Unpack these into keys in a lookup table (`lines`) in the `BEGIN` block, and then simply test whether `FNR` (the current line number in the current file) is a key in this lookup table.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

lineno="$*" awk '
        BEGIN {
                n = split(ENVIRON["lineno"], a, " ")
                for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
                        lines[a[i]] = 1
        }

        FNR in lines { print $1, $2 }'
```

(The `FNR in lines` could be changed to `lines[FNR]` so that the 1's that we store as values actually become useful.)

Testing:

```
$ ./get.sh 3 4 8 <data.txt
 3           cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
 4           dFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
 8           hFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

Comment: I wish my profs explained so verbosely n thoroughly, I would have maxed my grades.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

perl -le '
for (@ARGV) {
  # separate command line args into filename(s) and line-number(s)
  # line-numbers can be space and/or comma separated.
  if (-e $_) { push @files, $_ } else { push @lines, split /,/};
};

@ARGV = @files;
$re = join("|",@lines);

while(<>) {
  print join("\t",(split)[0..1]) if ($. =~ m/^($re)$/);
  close(ARGV) if eof;
}' "$@"
```

This builds a regex from the non-filename arguments, which it later uses to match against each file's line-numbers.  On a match, it splits the input line by whitespace and prints the first two fields separated by a tab.

The `close(ARGV)` is only needed because we care about the line number of the current file, not the line-number of all input seen so far.  perl only resets the `$.` (aka `$NR` or `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER`) variable when a file handle is closed, but file handles aren't normally closed in a `while(<>)` loop.  This just explicitly closes the filehandle so that `$.` is reset.  See `perldoc -f eof`.

```
$ ./get.sh 1 3,5 data.txt 
1       aFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
3       cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
5       eFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

---

This script, should, of course be a perl script instead of a pointless bash wrapper around a perl "one-liner".  But people seem to think that one-liners are "correct", while scripts that use anything except #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh as the interpreter are somehow wrong.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

for (@ARGV) {
  # separate command line args into filename(s) and line-number(s)
  # line-numbers can be space and/or comma separated.
  if (-e $_) { push @files, $_ } else { push @lines, split /,/ };
};

@ARGV = @files;
$re = join('|',@lines);

while(<>) {
  print join("\t",(split)[0..1]) if ($. =~ m/^($re)$/);
  close(ARGV) if eof;
};
```

```
$ ./get.pl 1 3,5 data.txt  
1       aFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
3       cFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
5       eFDLKSFD_FDSJFskadfsff_fsadklfj_fdsaf
```

This does **exactly** the same thing without wasting miniscule amounts of time and memory forking a shell interpreter which does nothing but fork the perl interpreter.

More importantly, it avoids issues with **shell quoting** because the shell is not involved.  Also, **syntax highlighting** works correctly in your editor because the script isn't just a single quoted string inside a shell script.  And **line-numbers** are correct in warning/error messages when debugging a script because they refer to the absolute line-number of the script file, rather than the relative line number inside the one-liner.

Comment: +1 Not only for providing the 'hows' but also the 'whys' , for they fill in an important backgrounder information too. It's all like not only providing green veggies for lunch but also listing out their many pros n cons. (Me just got up from lunch so this analogy was uppermost )

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash
# get.sh
IFS=$'\n'
args=(`sort -nu <<<$*`)
unset IFS

awk -v lines="${args[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(lines, ar, " ");}{ for (i in ar) { if (NR == ar[i]) print $1,$2} }' data.txt
```

In this first an array `args` is created that contains sorted and unique
values.We have used options `-n` and `-u` for this. See for [more
detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11789688/13977360).

Then `split` creates an array `ar` from variable `lines`. Now for loop
print the required output if element in `ar` equals to record
number(NR).